# Computing the expectation $E[2^{X1+X2+X3}]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose that $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are three independent random variables satisfying

$$ P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=−1)=\frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{for} \ i = 1,2,3 $$

I am asked to find $E[2^{X1+X2+X3}]$.

So far I have worked out $E[X_i]=0$ from symmetry and tried to separate using Fubini's:

$$ E[2^{X_1}]E[2^{X_2}]E[2^{X_3}] $$

however I am stuck on how to proceed or whether this is the right route.

Comment: Hint: law of the unconscious statistician, i.e., the definition of expectation of functions of random variables.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $Y=\frac{X+1}{2}$ is bernulli $B(1/2)$ thus $\Sigma_i Y_i\sim Bin(3;1/2)$ and thus $\Sigma_i X_i$ takes the values

$$\{-3;-1;1;3\}$$

with probabilities

$$\{1/8;3/8;3/8;1/8\}$$

And thus $2^{\Sigma_i X_i}$ takes the values

$$\{1/8;1/2;2;8\}$$

with the same probabilities...

Concluding:

$$\mathbb{E} [2^{\Sigma_i X_i}]=\frac{1}{64}+   \frac{3}{16}+  \frac{6}{8} +1=\frac{125}{64} $$

---

This matches  with your reasoning being

$$E(2^{X_1})=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\frac{1}{2}+2\Bigg]=\frac{5}{4}$$

Comment: Is there another way to get to the answer using Laws of Expectation?

Answer (score 1):

Let's just follow the definition

$E(s^X)=s^1 \cdot P(X=1)+s^{-1} \cdot P(X=-1)=s \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}+s^{-1}\dfrac{1}{2}$

In our case, we have $s=2$

so,

$E(2^X)=(2) \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}+(2)^{-1}\dfrac{1}{2}=1+\dfrac{1}{4}=\dfrac{5}{4}$

but we have

$E(2^{X_{1}}2^{X_{2}}2^{X_{3}})=E(2^{X_{1}})E(2^{X_{2}})E(2^{X_{3}})=\dfrac{5}{4}\cdot\dfrac{5}{4}\cdot\dfrac{5}{4}$

$E(ABC)=E(A)E(B)E(C)$ is possible because of independence.